# What part of speech is 'на!' when used for 'take!'?

Tags: грамматика

Not sure what part of speech 'на!' is when used in the meaning of 'take!'

Comment: It's a particle used in collouial speech, every modern Russian dictionary says that. Older ones, like Dahl or Vasmer, qualify it as an interjection.

Comment: @YellowSky Why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 4):

When you use `на` like `take`, it is **not** an interjection `"междометие"`, and of course it is **not** a verb `"глагол"`, it's a particle `"частица"` (colloquial).
Prooflink: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%ED%E0&all=x

Answer (score 0):

It is interjection (Междометие) http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.BD.D0.B0_II

Answer (score -1):

It is междометие (interjection).